# How do I make it so that select button will only appear if the column value is the same as the User ID?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How do I make it so that select button will only appear if the Doctor column value is the same as the User ID? For example, the current User ID is Dr.One. So i want it so that only rows that is entered by that Dr will show the select button, but hide it from rows with other Doctor's names.

```
<tr>
  <td>No</td>
  <td>Description</td>
  <td>Doctor</td>
  <td><button>Select</button></td>
</tr>
<tr> // This is the row that is entered by the current User ID
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Anything</td>
  <td>Dr.One</td>
  <td>Select</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Anything</td>
  <td>Dr.Two</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

Currently i'm using AJAX to load the table, i tried to put if-else in between the `<td>`, but it gives syntax error.

```
      $.ajax({
            url: '/Consultation/GetMyList',
            type: 'GET',
            data: $('#frmMyList').serialize(), // it will serialize the form data
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {

                var rowNum = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rowNum += 1;
                    $("#LoadMyListTable tbody").append("<tr Class='odd gradeX subsequentmyList '>" +
                                "<td>" + rowNum + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + data[i].Description + "</td>" +
                                "<td>" + data[i].UserID + "</td>" +
                                "<td style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'><button type='button' class='select btn btn-default' data-refid='" + data[i].RefID + "'>Select</button></td>" +
                    "</tr>");
                }

            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Ajax Submit Failed ...');
            }
        }); // end ajax
```

GetMyList method

```
public List<Consultation> GetMyList(String paid, string UserID)
    {
        using (DbContext dbb = new DbContext())
        {
            var query = from p in dbb.patient
                        join pv in dbb.patient_visit on p.paid equals pv.paid
                        join d in dbb.diagnosis on pv.pvid equals d.pvid
                        join u in dbb.users on d.enteredby equals u.UserID
                        where p.paid.Equals(paid)
                        orderby d.entereddt descending
                        select new { d.RefID, d.Description, u.UserID, d.enteredby };

            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                Consultation List = new Consultation();
                List.RefID = item.RefID;
                List.UserID = item.UserID;
                List.Description = item.Description;
                List.enteredby = item.enteredby;
                LoadMyList.Add(List);
            }

            return LoadMyList;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What is your `GetMyList()` controller method. Its return data should include a `bool` value to indicate if the the button should be shown or not, and then you can use a javascript `if` block.

Comment: Is the user ID available to your JS in a variable or something? (The code shown doesn't include it.) If you want to include an if/else in the middle of a string concatenation you need to use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: Well, simply use `<hasbutton>[true/false]</hasbutton>` which deserialized as `bool` property `hasbutton` instead of adding HTML button tag. In JS side, you can toggle the button appearance based on passed `hasbutton` viewmodel property with `if` condition and `show`/`hide` method.

Comment: @nnnnnn its in the layout page and also in the view(in one of the input tag), but not in the JS

Comment: You can split the concat string into 2 section and second part shall be adding about button and use if(data[i].DoctorName =='XXXX') { add or not button)

Comment: Instead of directly appending you could first do your logic store the tags in a var and then append it to the table to avoid syntax errors

Comment: var xyz=" ";
                xyz+= "<tr><td style='border-right: solid 1px #5090c1;border-left: solid 1px #5090c1;'>" + data1 + "</td><td style='border-right: solid 1px #5090c1;border-left: solid 1px #5090c1;'>" + data2 + "</td></tr>";

Comment: @StephenMuecke where should i put the if block? I couldnt do it inside the append string

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I've tried but now it didn't show any rows at all :( is it wrong somewhere? `"<td>" + data[i].consultingDr == $("#UserID").val() ?  + "<button type='button' class='select btn btn-default' data-diid='" + data[i].diid + "'>Select</button></td>" : "</td>"`

Comment: @Nurul, I lot of what you have shown makes no sense (you have a `Date` column but are not returning a date, and you do not even return a value for  `Doctor` so its hard to understand what your wanting to do. but you can build your html using jquery - `var row - $('<tr></tr>'); row.append($('<td></td>').text(data.data[i].Description)); if (data[i].ShowDoctor) { ...... };` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke if i did that, can i remove the appended rows and reload the updated rows after i do a form submission using AJAX? I was thinking of letting the append `<tr>` be in one lump code so that i could lump them as a class and after form submit using AJAX, then i could do remove() and re-append them back that way

Comment: Yes, of course you can. To clear all roes, use something like `$('yourTableBodyElementID').empty();`. But you question is so vague its not possible to give you an answer unless you include all the relevant information.

Comment: Still not making sense. Your query filters by `d.UserID.Equals(UserID)` so it appears you only ever return the rows you want to have the button anyway so you do not need an `if` block (they will all have the button)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143744/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-nurul).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a `bool SbowButton` property in your `Consultation` view model (or just pass back a collection of anonymous objects.

```
var query = from p in dbb.patient
    .....
var data = query.Select(x => new
{
    RefID = x.RefID,
    UserID = x.UserID,
    Description = x.Description,
    ShowButton = x.UserID == yourCurrentUserID // not sure of your logic here    
});
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then in the ajax success call back, build your html conditionally

```
var table = $('#LoadMyListTable tbody'); // cache it
$.ajax({
    ....
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
            var row = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('odd gradeX subsequentmyList');
            row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.RefID));
            row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.Description));
            row.append($('<td></td>').text(item.UserID));
            var buttonCell = $('<td></td>');
            if (item.ShowButton) {
                var button = $('<button></button>').attr('type', 'button').addClass('select btn btn-default').data('refid', item.RefID).html('Select');
                buttonCell.append(button);
            }
            row.append(buttonCell);
            table.apend(row);
        });
    }
    ....
});
```

Comment: This snippet `var data = query.Select(x => new...` do i put it in viewmodel or in controller? The code i showed above is in viewmodel. Do i have to separate the select clause from my original query?

Comment: `var data = query.Select(x => new { ... });` replaces your `foreach` loop in the controller method. If `Consultation` is a view model and you can add the `bool ShowButton` property, then it just becomes `var data = query.Select(x => new Consultation { ... });`

Comment: The previous query i did before `var query = from p in dbb.patient join pv in dbb.patient_visit...` Do i leave it the same as before, and after that query, add this `var data = query.Select(x => new Consultation { ... });`? Because if i try to remove `select new {..` from my original query, it wont let me

Comment: No, leave your `var query = from p in dbb.patient .....` code as it is.

Comment: In the viewmodel, i declare the `ShowButton` as `public bool ShowButton { get; set; }` and in the `var data = query.Select(x => new Consultation { ` when i add `ShowButton = x.enteredby == UserID ? true : false` it shows false. Its supposed to be true. Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: Lets go back into the chat room